# Bootstrap badge colour is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I am trying to highlight the text "true" or "false" based on their values, if the value is **true**, I want the label to be green, if the value is **false**, I want the label to be red. I wrote this code in my index.html.erb file.
Here is the code:

```
<%= @valid_feed_sync = true %>
<% class_feed = @valid_feed_sync == 'true' ? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger'%>
<b>Valid:</b> <span class="<%=class_feed%>"> <%=@valid_feed_sync%> </span></h4>
```

But, am always getting the label in red colour, irrespective of their values.

Comment: So what you are saying is it can sometimes have the class of `label-success` but still be red? Or are you saying the correct class is not getting applied from the conditional?

Comment: Could you please put the result of your erb template compiling. You can see it opening your browser console.

Comment: ...Also could you tell us: which version of bootstrap are you using? maybe that would have been **badge badge-success** instead of "label..."

Answer (score 1):

in  `<% class_feed = @valid_feed_sync == 'true' ? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger'%>`

You are comparing a boolean with a string so the condition always falls into the else case.

Try this: `<% class_feed = @valid_feed_sync == true ? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger'%>`

Comment: Instead of `@valid_feed_sync == true` you might just want to use `@valid_feed_sync`. There is no point in explicitly check if a true-ish value is actually `true`